# Building mvc3 application with msbuild and nuget restore packages

Tags: deployment, msbuild, nuget

When I try to build my mvc3 application with Visual Studio 2010 Prompt. I get this error:

> "TournamentCompanion.csproj" (default target) (1) ->  TournamentCompanion.csproj(553,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "TournamentCompanion(1)\.nuget\nuget.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

, but the import in the .csproj says:

> Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuge\nuget.targets"

and this is what my solution looks like:

project

- .nuget
- TournamentCompanion
  | TournamentCompanion.csproj
- TournamentCompanion.Tests
- TournamentCompanion.sln

I can't find a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead and see if you get the same error:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\.nuget\nuget.targets" />
```

It has the additional benefit of not using a solution-relative path, clearing the way for you to build without the solution file at all if you want a stronger foundation on which to construct an industrial strength command line build.

[Excerpted from [MSBuild Trickery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/061550907X) trick #80]

Comment: thx, for the solution. I did have to change the NuGet.targets file as wel.
From:
<NuGetToolsPath Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT'">$([System.IO.Path]::Combine($(SolutionDir), ".nuget"))</NuGetToolsPath>
To:
<NuGetToolsPath Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT'">$([System.IO.Path]::Combine($(MSBuildThisFileDirectory), ".nuget"))</NuGetToolsPath>
and then it worked

Comment: I always place a Nuget.config file in a root folder above all solution/project files, and redirect nuget to a single location in the repository.
<configuration>
   <packagesDirectory>./Packages</packagesDirectory>
</configuration>